# Nginx rewrite that includes a blank spce

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

A client of ours has created a QR code that includes a blank space in the url.
How would I write an nginx redirect that dealt with this problem?

A couple of attempts using things like "%20" in the string seem to cause nginx to error or fail the configtest

To be precise the QR code reads like this

http://www.google.com/somestuff /someotherstuf/pagewewant

and I need to re direct it to

http://www.google.com/somestuff/someotherstuf/pagewewant
(The re write should show no blank space after somestuff )

Thanks for your time

Comment: you mean rewrite "/somestuff " /somestuff break; doesn't work?

Comment: can you post your nginx config with your current rewrite?

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the exact same problem.
The reason you can't use %20 is, that nginx will interpret the uri, so %20 will not match:

```
http request line: "GET /something/%20something HTTP/1.1"
http uri: "/something/ something"
```

I don't wanted to use a location for this, so I used:

```
rewrite ^/something/\ something /something/something permanent;
```

This worked just fine for me.

Answer (score 4):

Question is over two years old, but maybe it'll save someone some headaches.

Word of warning: I am no nginx expert. It's just one the things I tried after finding this unanswered question and it happened to work. It may not be the best way to do that. I would recommend checking the nginx documentation in case one is looking at handling a significantly large amount of such locations.

For the occasional rewrite including spaces I put the path in single quotes:

```
location '/level_one /landingpage.htm' { 
rewrite ^ http://www.foo.bar/level_one/landingpage.htm permanent; }
```

If for some reason you need to have spaces in the target put that in single quotes as well:

```
location '/downloads/foo bar.pdf' { 
rewrite ^ 'http://www.foo.bar/documents/foo bar.pdf' permanent; }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to remove spaces from a URL and then redirect to the stripped URL without the spaces simply use the following to catch all URLs with the issue:

```
rewrite ^(.*)(\s|%20)(.*)$ $1$3 permanent;
```

This is basically grabbing everything before the first occurrence of a space `\s` or a URL encoded space `%20` in capture group 1 (`$1`). The spaces are then captured in group 2 (`$2`). Then finally anything left over past group 2 is captured in group 3 (`$3`). I then join capture groups 1 and 3 together (`$1$3`) to form the redirect URL without the spaces in capture group 2 (`$2`).

This will work with a URL with multiple spaces throughout the URL, but it is working one at a time. So the URL with 2 spaces in it, will then redirect to the URL with 1 space and then finally to URL with no spaces.

You can of course change the redirect type from permanent if you wish. This will currently redirect with a 301 code.

Comment: `rewrite ^(.*)(\s|%20)+(.*)$ $1$3 permanent;` is a little bit better